# Reading variable from a txt file using bash

Tags: bash, declare

I'm new to bash.

I'm trying to write a script that will read data from a text find and declare some variables. In the example below we read from a tab delimited file "ab.txt" that looks like this:

a->AA

b->BB

Where -> denotes a tab.

I'm reading this data with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    tmp=(${line///})
    fieldName=${tmp[0]}

    case $fieldName in
    "a")
        a=${tmp[1]}
        ;;
    "b")
        b=${tmp[1]}
        ;;
    esac

done < "ab.txt"


echo "a:"
echo $a 

echo "b:"
echo $b

echo "concat a,b"
echo $a$b

echo "concat b,a"
echo $b$a
```

This gives me "a" and "b" nicely, but will not concatenate a and b!
The output is this:

```
a:
AA
b:
BB
concat a,b
BB
concat b,a
AA
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"This gives me "a" and "b" nicely"` Are you sure even that part is correct? According to the code you should only be getting `A` and `B` instead of `AA` and `BB`. When I ran your code I got that result and all concats were correct as well. Are you sure your input is correct?

Comment: Agree with @kaylum, running your script gives me the desired output.

Comment: The `AA` versus `A` is presumably a transcription error - however the apparent failure to concatenate is possibly another case of Windows (CRLF) line endings i.e. `AA\rBB\r` will appear as just `BB`

Comment: @steeldriver, that was it. I used dos2unix on the "ab.txt" file and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Rather than `read`ing the entire line and then splitting it into an array, I'd let `read` do the splitting: `while IFS=$\t\ read fieldName fieldValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@steedriver found the problem:
In windows the end of lines have escape characters that linux doesn't have. I created the input text file ab.txt in windows, so linux read the extra characters into the a, b variables.
My solution was to convert ab.text using dos2unix, that worked.